# Drupal Webforms arrange fields and labels

Tags: webforms

I need to create form like below

```
Label(Full Name)     TextField            Textfield

                 Label(First Name)    Label(Last Name)
```

How can I achieve this in webforms?
In webforms there is no option to show labels below.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module [Arrange Fields](http://drupal.org/project/arrange_fields) which will help you.With this modle you can Drag and drop fields into any arrangement you want.

Answer (score 0):

use field legend for(***Label(Full Name)***) and ***Label(First Name)*** this the name of field , to show  form like this you can mange it from the css 
you can fiend some model like this http://drupal.org/project/formdefaults can help you to add more text